# Importxml and importhtml don´t give me the data from the table in website that I need (only headers)

Tags: html, google-sheets-formula

I´m trying to take information from a website to googlesheets and I tried with importxml and importhtml, but it´s not working.

https://www.fpf.pt/pt/Jogadores/Ficha-de-Jogador/playerId/1871569

First I tried with Importhtml, only appear the headers:

```
=IMPORTHTML(A1;"table";1)
```

A1:

```
https://www.fpf.pt/pt/Jogadores/Ficha-de-Jogador/playerId/1871569
```

Result from formula (No Data):

```
Época   Clube   Modalidade  Escalão
{{item.Season}} {{item.Name}}{{item.Name}}  {{item.SportTypeName}}  {{item.FootballClassName}}
```

Then I tried with importxml to appear one column only:

```
/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/section/div/article/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]
```

Result from formula (No data):

```
{{item.Season}}
```

Could anyone help me understand what i´m doing wrong?

Thank You Very Much

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to find another site with intel you attempting to scrape. the empty table is the result of google sheets not supporting the import of JavaScript elements. you can always check for compatibility by disabling JS in site settings and only what's left can be usually scrapped. in this case its nothing:

[image]